# Proof that $ d(x,y) : = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{d_{i}(x,y)}{1+d_{i}(x,y)}$ defines a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider a countable family of metric space $(M_{i},d_{i})_{i=0}^\infty$ and the Cartesian product $M := \prod_{i=0}^\infty M_{i}$. Show that    $ d(x,y) : = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{d_{i}(x,y)}{1+d_{i}(x,y)}$ defines a metric on $M$.

I know so far, that $\frac{d_{}(x,y)}{1+d_{}(x,y)}$ defines a metric and I assume that it would be a semi metric of $ d(x,y) : = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{d_{i}(x,y)}{1+d_{i}(x,y)}$. However I do not know how to attempt the proof here, that it is a metric. Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x,y\in M$, then\begin{align}d(x,y)=0&\iff\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^i}\frac{d_i(x,y)}{1+d_i(x,y)}=0\\&\iff(\forall i\in\mathbb{N}_0):d_i(x,y)=0\\&\iff x=y.\end{align}Besides\begin{align}d(x,y)&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^i}\frac{d_i(x,y)}{1+d_i(x,y)}\\&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^i}\frac{d_i(y,x)}{1+d_i(y,x)}\\&=d(y,x).\end{align}Finally, if $z\in M$, then\begin{align}d(x,z)&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^i}\frac{d_i(x,z)}{1+d_i(x,z)}\\&\leqslant\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^i}\frac{d_i(x,y)}{1+d_i(x,y)}+\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{2^i}\frac{d_i(y,z)}{1+d_i(y,z)}\\&=d(x,y)+d(y,z).\end{align}**Note:** As pointed out in the comments, the last inequality comes from the fact that$$(\forall i\in\mathbb{N}_0):d_i(x,z)\leqslant d_i(x,y)+d_i(y,z)$$and from the fact that, if you define $f\colon[0,+\infty)\longrightarrow[0,+\infty)$ by $f(x)=\frac x{1+x}$, then$$\bigl(\forall x,y\in[0,+\infty)\bigr):f(x+y)\leqslant f(x)+f(y).$$

Comment: The last inequality coming from the fact that $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is convex and thus subadditive.

Comment: @Julien RIght. I will add that.